# Juniper SSG-5 subinterface vlan routing to the internet

Tags: vlan, juniper, ssg5

I'm unable to get a brand new Juniper SSG-5 with latest 6.3.0r05 firmware routing to the internet from a subinterface I created on bgroup0 setup as vlan2 (bgroup0.1 on "wifi" zone). When connected on the default vlan it gets on the internet just fine.

When I switch to vlan2 I'm unable to get to the internet. I am able to get the correct ip address (10.150.0.0/24) from dhcp, able to get to the juniper management page, etc but nothing past the firewall, can't ping 4.2.2.2 or the internet gateway. Even setting up logging on the wifi-to-untrust policy and it does shows the attempts (it's it's timeouts).

172.31.16.0/24 is the untrusted lan, it's already nat'ed but works fine for testing. Can ping this ip from the default vlan but not from vlan2
192.168.1.0/24 is the trusted main lan
10.150.0.0/24 is the wifi isolated lan on vlan2

The idea is to setup an AP with lan and guest access (AP supports multiple ssid's on different vlans). I know I can setup the juniper to use different ports for the wifi lan and use their procurve switch to do the vlan separation, but I never used vlan'ing on a Juniper firewall and I would like to try it out this way.

Here is the complete config file:

```
unset key protection enable
set clock timezone -5
set vrouter trust-vr sharable
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set alg appleichat enable
unset alg appleichat re-assembly enable
set alg sctp enable
set auth-server "Local" id 0
set auth-server "Local" server-name "Local"
set auth default auth server "Local"
set auth radius accounting port 1646
set admin name "netscreen"
set admin password "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
set admin auth web timeout 10
set admin auth dial-in timeout 3
set admin auth server "Local"
set admin format dos
set zone "Trust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "DMZ" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "VLAN" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone id 100 "Wifi"
set zone "Untrust-Tun" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Trust" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" block 
unset zone "Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "MGT" block 
unset zone "V1-Trust" tcp-rst 
unset zone "V1-Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "DMZ" tcp-rst 
unset zone "V1-DMZ" tcp-rst 
unset zone "VLAN" tcp-rst 
unset zone "Wifi" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "Untrust" screen land
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen land
set interface "ethernet0/0" zone "Untrust"
set interface "ethernet0/1" zone "Untrust"
set interface "bgroup0" zone "Trust"
set interface "bgroup0.1" tag 2 zone "Wifi"
set interface "bgroup1" zone "DMZ"
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/2
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/3
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/4
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/5
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/6
unset interface vlan1 ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip 172.31.16.243/24
set interface ethernet0/0 route
set interface bgroup0 ip 192.168.1.1/24
set interface bgroup0 nat
set interface bgroup0.1 ip 10.150.0.1/24
set interface bgroup0.1 nat
set interface bgroup0.1 mtu 1500
unset interface vlan1 bypass-others-ipsec
unset interface vlan1 bypass-non-ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0.1 ip manageable
set interface ethernet0/0 manage ping
set interface ethernet0/1 manage ping
set interface bgroup0.1 manage ping
set interface bgroup0.1 manage telnet
set interface bgroup0.1 manage web
unset interface bgroup1 manage ping
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server auto
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server enable
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option gateway 192.168.1.1 
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option netmask 255.255.255.0 
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option dns1 8.8.8.8 
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server option lease 1440 
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server option gateway 10.150.0.1 
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server option netmask 255.255.255.0 
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server option dns1 8.8.8.8 
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server ip 192.168.1.33 to 192.168.1.126 
set interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server ip 10.150.0.50 to 10.150.0.100 
unset interface bgroup0 dhcp server config next-server-ip
unset interface bgroup0.1 dhcp server config next-server-ip
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" init "AT&F"
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" active
set interface "serial0/0" modem speed 115200
set interface "serial0/0" modem retry 3
set interface "serial0/0" modem interval 10
set interface "serial0/0" modem idle-time 10
set flow tcp-mss
unset flow no-tcp-seq-check
set flow tcp-syn-check
unset flow tcp-syn-bit-check
set flow reverse-route clear-text prefer
set flow reverse-route tunnel always
set pki authority default scep mode "auto"
set pki x509 default cert-path partial
set crypto-policy
exit
set ike respond-bad-spi 1
set ike ikev2 ike-sa-soft-lifetime 60
unset ike ikeid-enumeration
unset ike dos-protection
unset ipsec access-session enable
set ipsec access-session maximum 5000
set ipsec access-session upper-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session lower-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session dead-p2-sa-timeout 0
unset ipsec access-session log-error
unset ipsec access-session info-exch-connected
unset ipsec access-session use-error-log
set url protocol websense
exit
set policy id 1 from "Trust" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit 
set policy id 1
exit
set policy id 2 from "Wifi" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit log 
set policy id 2
exit
set nsmgmt bulkcli reboot-timeout 60
set ssh version v2
set config lock timeout 5
unset license-key auto-update
set telnet client enable
set snmp port listen 161
set snmp port trap 162
set snmpv3 local-engine id "0162122009006149"
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset add-default-route
set route 0.0.0.0/0 interface ethernet0/0 gateway 172.31.16.1
exit
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
exit
```

Comment: Same problem with 6.3.0r03 firmware

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue. I had to enable Source Nat on the Wifi-to-Untrust policy. I'm not sure why it's needed (the default policy for Trust-to-Untrust doesn't have it). You enable the option in the advanced section of the policy or change the line posted above:

```
set policy id 2 from "Wifi" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit log
```

to:

```
set policy id 2 from "Wifi" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" nat src permit log
```

Comment: There may be an implied trust to untrust nat or it might be included automatically via a checkbox on the untrust interface?